# SQL Select and Count Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follows

```
 --------------------------------
 ChildId | ChildName | ParentId |
 --------------------------------
    1    |     A     |    0     |
 --------------------------------
    2    |     B     |    1     |
 --------------------------------
    3    |     C     |    1     |
 --------------------------------
```

I would like to select data as -

```
 ---------------------------------------
     Id   |    Name    |     Childs    |
 ---------------------------------------
     1    |      A     |       2       |
 ---------------------------------------
     2    |      B     |       0       |
 ---------------------------------------
     3    |      C     |       0       |
 ---------------------------------------
```

The pseudo SQL statement should be like this-

```
SELECT ChildId AS Id, ChildName as Name, (Count (ParentId) Where ParentId=ChildId)
```

Any Help?

Comment: What if B has  a child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT ChildId AS Id, ChildName as Name, (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM TestCountOver T WHERE T.ParentID = O.ChildID) FROM TestCountOver O
```

but that would give you all the nodes plus children who shouldn't be part of the hierarchy

If you want only nodes with children then use a cte

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT ChildId AS Id, ChildName as Name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TestCountOver T WHERE T.ParentID = O.ChildID) Cnt FROM TestCountOver O
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE Cnt > 0
```

Comment: Takes me forever to write the answer :P
Giorgi's answer is the better bet

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick:

```
select t1.childid, t1.childname, count(*) as childs
from table t1
join table t2 on t1.childid = t2.parentid
group by t1.childid, t1.childname
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one level you can use the approach in your pseudo code. It should look like this:

```
SELECT 
    ChildId AS Id, 
    ChildName as Name, 
    (select Count(ParentId) from t t_inner Where ParentId=t_outer.ChildId) children
from t t_outer
-- optionally where clause to limit result to parents that have children
where exists (select 1 from t where ParentId in (t_outer.ChildId))
```

but if there can be more than one level you can solve it using a recursive query if you want the total number of children for a parent (including grand-children etc).